# How to make card body horizontal in small screens in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to how to make card horizontal in small(mobile) screens using bootstrap 4.

Below image as shown, card vertical in desktop/larger screens and card horizontal in mobile/smaller screens.

[image]

```
 <div class="card-deck py-4">
      <div class="card">
          <img src="../images/providers/tw-s01.svg" style="width:100%" class="card-imm-3"/>
              <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="card-title card-headtext">step 1</div>
                  <div class="card-text cardtext">Register for a free 
                  account</div>
              </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap classes like .col-sm (for small screens) .col-lg(for large) and so on combine these classes to adjust your divs for every device 
read more here
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp